Как настроить подсветку ошибок в редакторе vscode согласно Eslint?
Не получается настроить подсветку ошибок и авто исправление при сохранении файла согласно настройкам Eslint в vscode
Расширение Eslint установлено
Конфигурация файла eslint.config.mjs:
import globals from "globals";
import js from "@eslint/js";
import airbnbBase from "eslint-config-airbnb-base";
import importPlugin from "eslint-plugin-import";

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.node,
      },
    },
  },
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    plugins: {
      import: importPlugin,
    },
    rules: {
      ...airbnbBase.rules,
    },
  },
];

Файл package.json:
{
  "name": "eslint-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Настройки vscode:
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 0.3,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
  },
  "eslint.options": {
    "overrideConfigFile": "eslint.config.js"
  },
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark"
  // "standard.autoFixOnSave": true
}

Я пытался устранить ошибку с помощью чат ботов не помогает

Как минимум вам стоит отказаться от prettier. Настройте для нужных языков форматер от eslint.
